# How can I cleanly resize an iFrame with dragging functionality?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have an iFrame and I want the user to be able to grab one side of it and drag it to resize it. I don't want it to resize realtime, but rather use an indicator line and when the user releases, it'll resize.

I'm using jQuery.

Any help?

Comment: Place some DIV's at the edges of the IFRAME. Implement dragging functionality on those DIV's. At the mouseup-handler, determine the DIV position and set the IFRAME dimensions accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iirc, the classical method is to put the IFrame inside of a div and make that div re-sizable; also make the iFrame's width and height at 100%.

If you're using JQuery though, can you not use jQuery.load('uri') instead of an iFrame ? I believe it's preferable in many situations.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2020 you can simply add the CSS property `resize: both` or `resize: vertical` to the iframe element.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[jQuery Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#helper) with an indicator as to the eventual dimensions as per your request.</strike> See Russ C's comment and link to a better solution

Comment: That plugin has/had problems with raw iFrames:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509118/trouble-using-jquery-ui-resizable-and-ui-draggable-with-an-iframe

Comment: Thanks Russ, that's a far better solution.

Comment: What about the drag / snap functionality?

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#visual-feedback

That seems to do the trick with an iFrame inside a DIV