# OnClick, displaying div of page1 into page2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 html pages. main.html, page1.html and page2.html. I am displaying page1.html and page2.html in main.html using following code.

```
<html>
   <frameset frameborder="1" rows="50%, *">
        <frame src="page1.html" />
        <frame src="page2.html"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

page1.html code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="myjs.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
         <table id="resultDetails">
               <th>Result Details</th>
               <tr>
                  <td>Row 1</td>
                  <div id="r1">
                       <p> R1 data</p>
                  </div>
               </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And Page2.html code

```
<html>
   <body>
         <div id="myDiv">
              <p> Testing.... </p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript myjs.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table tr').on('click', function () {
                $('#r1').load('page2.html#myDiv');
        }); 
        });
```

With this code, on click on table row, i am able to display the "myDiv" content in "r1". But I want reverse behavior. i.e., on clicking row, content of div "r1" of page1 should be displayed in div "myDiv" of page2.
I tried  $('page2.html#myDiv').html('#r1'); but no success.
Any thoughts

Comment: Did you try $("#myDiv").html("page1.html#r1") ?

Comment: @Qqwy: I tried your code. no success. Also I tried $('page2.html#myDiv').html('page1.html#r1'); , still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible change the `frames` to `iframes`. You are then able to access the elements in each of the iframes by using the `.contents()` function assuming the two iframes are on the same domain.

You would then do something like the following.

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="myjs.js"></script>
   </head>
    <iframe id="page_1" src="page1.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="page_2" src="page2.html"></iframe>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
         <table id="resultDetails">
               <th>Result Details</th>
               <tr>
                  <td>Row 1</td>
                  <div id="r1">
                       <p> R1 data</p>
                  </div>
               </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
         <div id="myDiv">
              <p> Testing.... </p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myjs.js**

```
$(window).on('load',function () {
    $('#page_1').contents().bind('click','tr', function () {
        $('#page_2').contents().find('#myDiv').html($('#page_1').contents().find('#r1').html())
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the fix. This Works great. But Using iframes, I am not able to resize(move) the frames using sash which is possible using frames.

Comment: This should be a solution to that problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194302/how-can-i-cleanly-resize-an-iframe-with-dragging-functionality

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. Also I found that, for frames, using top.frames["frameID"].document.getElementById('divID'), we can access the element of other page. Thanks again for providing resolution.